# Simultaneously process two XML files with Haskell and HXT

Tags: xml, haskell, hxt

I have two XML files that I need to parse into one record.  The first document contains data for most of the record, but there is a field holds an identifier for fetching data from the second XML file, somewhat like

File 1:

```
<nodes>
    <node>
        <key1>value1</key1>
        <!-- etc -->
        <keyN>valueN</keyN>
        <reference>1</reference
    </node>
</nodes>
```

File 2:

```
<refs>
    <ref id="1">refValue1</ref>
    <ref id="2">refValue2</ref>
</refs>
```

What I would like to do is while parsing the first document, retrieving the values from the key elements, is when I extract the value of `<reference>`, I immediately fetch the contents of `<ref id="1">` from the second file.

Since I am very new to Arrows, this is proving to be quite a challenge for me to figure out how to do.  I'm able to parse the first XML file just fine, but I don't know how to pass in the second document to be used on demand.

Comment: You could parse the second file into a `Map`, and then get the `ref` values out of that while parsing the first file to the record.

Comment: This might work.  I'll give it a try and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At phg's suggestion, I tried parsing the second XML file into a Map first, then passing it into the parser for the first XML file.  A little bit of fiddling and tweaking and I got it working.